# Excluding all characters NOT in list AND NOT in a list of phrases

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm attempting to make a function in PHP that will evaluate a mathematical expression -- including functions such as sin, cos, etc.  My approach is to delete all characters in the phrase that are not numbers, mathematical operators, or mathematical functions and then use that string in an eval().  The problem is that I don't know enough about regular expressions to negate both characters and phrases in the same expression.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
$input = preg_replace("/[^0-9+\-.*\/()sincota]/", "", $input);
```

Obviously, the characters for sin, cos, and tan can be used in any order in the input expression (rather than **only** allowing the phrases sin, cos, and tan).  If I further expand this function to include even more characters and functions, that presents an even bigger security risk as a malicious user would be able to execute just about any PHP command through clever interaction with the app.

Can anyone tell me how to fix my regex and eliminate this problem?

Comment: Hmm, there's a reason most languages throw syntax errors rather then trying a best guess, that way madness lies (and you have to be a very good guesser in some cases). Your solution is still a parser rather then regex (really, it isn't that hard), and voilà, no fear of executing 'any PHP command'. `eval=-evil` (in most cases...)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Comment: Thanks, Wrikken.  I haven't seen that in over a decade and had (rather inconveniently) forgotten about it.  I guess I'll have to write a parser instead of just trying to get away with a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attempting to make a function in
>   PHP that will evaluate a mathematical
>   expression -- including functions such
>   as sin, cos, etc

Might I suggest taking advantage of the years of work that has been put into [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), which includes a formula parser already.

It includes `cos`, `sin` and hundreds of others.

Otherwise, rather than negating, you can look for positive matches:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("#([0-9,/\*()+\s\.-]|sin|cos)+#", 'sin(12) + cos(13.5/2) evddal * (4-1)', $matches);
echo implode('', $matches[0]);

/* output:
sin(12) + cos(13.5/2) * (4-1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
preg_replace("/(sin|cos|tan)?[^0-9+\\.*\/()-]/", "$1", $input);
```

[code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/DUPig)

But if you're trying to parse an expression to evaluate it, I suggest you to **parse** it and not simply pass it through a regular expression pattern.